# How to remove previous fragment before call the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have GridView Which is showing in fragment, the GridView contain the number of items, the number of fragments will be open when i click on any item.
It's working fine, but after opened fragment when i click on back press the fragment is removed but the problem is when i opened activity after that fragment back press the previous fragment is still showing.

I have implemented code as below in backpress of MainActivity

```
Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment);

        if (currentFragment instanceof Home) {
            removeFragmetns();
        } else if (currentFragment instanceof RemarksFragment) {

        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
```

and removefragments method is

```
public void removeFragmetns() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

When i call the fragment and activity
In Swich Case OnClickListener

```
 fragmentClass = SyncFragment.class;
                        GlobalConstant.whichFragment = "data";
                        title = web[position];
```

after the switch case

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment).commit();
```

Calling the activity in switch case onclicklistener

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                        Intent intentTasks = new Intent(getActivity(), TasksActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intentTasks);
```

Comment: Please guys help to solve it!!!

Comment: add the code u r using to open the fregment from grid adapter

Comment: just before u do fragmentManager.beginTransaction()........ call removeFragments(); after this call the fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); dont call removeFragment() from onBackpress();

Comment: but my GridView is also into the fragment, that is in home fragment.

Comment: so just make the loop limit -1 to current , ie. fm.getBackStackEntryCount()-1 -: for (int i = 0; i <( fm.getBackStackEntryCount()-1); ++i) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }

Comment: As you said i have remove removefragments from OnBackPress and have put before the begin transaction and changed loop , but the problem is same when i call the activity the previous fragment is showing first and after that redirect to that activity

Comment: make the removeFragments() method as it was before, one more thing is the fragment that contain the gridView is define inside the xml of activity or it is a seprate fragment, that you open from fm.beginTransaction().

Comment: the gridview is in fragment which is showing in activity after the login

Comment: Thanks!!! but It's not working for me!!! any another idea about it?